# Old Bugle broken?

Tags: brass

I recently got a bugle from an auction. I don’t know much about it but the part where the mouthpiece attaches looks like this. Could this affect the ability to play it?[image]

Comment: It looks normal at first glance. Could you be more specific about what concerns you?

Comment: @Aaron I'd guess that it's the split visible in the inner layer of metal inside the tube.

Comment: Yes I thought maybe that split meant it was broken. It doesn’t seem to hold the trumpet mouthpiece I got very tight.

Comment: Where was the bugle made?  What key is it in?  I have a vague recollection that bugle mouthpieces are typically somewhat different from trumpet mouthpieces, but the extent to which this is true probably depends on what kind of bugle it is.  Anyway, if air is leaking between the mouthpiece and the leadpipe then I suppose the answer to your question is "yes, it will affect the playability."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don’t know much about it, there’s no markings but I might have to try to find one in Better shape. I do know that the low note is G for the tuner. And I can play a little bit of C, E and G.  I’ve never played trumpet before so that is probably why I can’t get any notes out. Do you know of anywhere to get a new one or a good used one that doesn’t cost too much?

Comment: There was a guy who sold old bugles in the Waterlooplein market in Amsterdam about 20 years ago for fl 25 if I remember correctly.  I don't know if he's still there or how much he charges if he is.

Comment: If there **is** a leak, well, that's what duck tape is for [I'm JOKING]

Comment: Is there any way this could be fixed at least partially?